# ¿ Por qué obtengo como resultado [[PromiseResult]] = undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Tengo una **clase** donde con **axios** hago peticiones al servidor.
La idea es desde mi **componente Home** llamar a esta **clase** e implementar sus **metodos**,
como por ejemplo el **metodo getOperations** para obtener todas las operaciones de un usuario.
pero por consola obtengo esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aca la clase **OperationsService** para hacer la peticion al servidor.

```js
import axios from "axios";

class OperationsService{

    async getOperations() {
        
        //return Promise.resolve(this.items);
        try {
            const data = await axios
              .get("http://localhost:4000/api/operations/user/clau@gmail.com")
              .then((res) => {
                return (res.data);
              });
          } catch (e) {
            alert("Error al intentar obtener las operaciones");
          }       
    }

}

export default OperationsService;
```

Aca componente **Home** donde llamo a la clase **OperationsService**.

```js
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import OperationsService from "./../../operationsService"

const Home = () => {
    React.useEffect(() => {
    getOperations();
  }, []);

   const getOperations = async () => {
    let operationsService = new OperationsService();
    const data = operationsService.getOperations();
    console.log(data);
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puede ser la configuración `async/await` de `axios` en la clase `OperationsService`.

```
 //el resultado va en data, pero no se esta regresando
 const data = await axios
              .get("http://localhost:4000/api/operations/user/clau@gmail.com")
              .then((res) => {
                return (res.data);
              });
```

Asumiendo que el API endpoint regresa una llave `data`, se puede intentar lo siguiente:

```
import axios from "axios";

class OperationsService{

    async getOperations() {
        
        //return Promise.resolve(this.items);
        try {
              const {data} = await axios({
                method: "get", 
                url: "http://localhost:4000/api/operations/user/clau@gmail.com",
                responseType: "json"
                });
    
              return data;

          } catch (e) {
            alert("Error al intentar obtener las operaciones");
          }       
    }

}

export default OperationsService;
```

En el componente `Home`:

```
const Home = () => {
   useEffect(() => {
    getOperations();
  }, []);

  const getOperations = async () => {
    let operationsService = new OperationsService();
    const data = operationsService.getOperations();
    data.then(res => console.log(res));
    console.log(data);
  }

   return null;
}
```

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda!